# Can we write data to a config.properties file using FileWriter and BufferedWrirter combination in a key value pair format

Tags: fileinputstream, filewriter, properties-file, bufferedwriter

Using `FileWriter`, can I write the key value pair `username = "login_data"` to a `.properties` file instead of a `.txt` file?

```java
String value1 = "This is the value from FILE WRITER"; 
System.out.println("Key1 == " + value1);

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(dataFilePath, true);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

bw.write(value1);
bw.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

To store the properties it is much better to create a `Properties` object, put the values and save it via [`store()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)) method.

If you want to keep layout and comments too, it's worth looking at Apache Commons [`PropertiesConfigurationLayout`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/PropertiesConfigurationLayout.html):

```java
PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
PropertiesConfigurationLayout layout = new PropertiesConfigurationLayout();

config.setProperty("key", "value");
layout.setComment("key", "description of key");

layout.setHeaderComment("file description");

layout.save(config, new FileWriter (file));
```

Comment: Hi Zbynek Vyskovsky - kvr000,
I tried with the store metod of properties, but in the existing properties file i've few things with comments for each line to make others clear on each line in the properties file.

Here the thing is After storing the new line to the existing properties file, the comments of each line in the properties file are vanishing :( . Please let me know if there is any way.    :)